# Connect react native to local excel workbook - what do i need to learn?

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, react-native

I've built and app that uses the expo barcode scanner to read data and upload it to firebase. It's basically a booking in app for hire equipment.

We normally use excel to book in and out equipment, but I'm wondering whether I can modify the react native app and have it update my excel spreadsheets over the local wifi connection.

The problem is I'm not sure what I need to learn to make this a reality. I understand javascript and the libraries associated with react-native but my back end knowledge is not strong whatsoever.

Could someone advise what I would need to learn in order to build this app? Or is there something I can use which is reasonably straight forward.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this question is relevant for this forum. You might want to consider adding this question in something like **SuperUser** forum?

Comment: you want to update excel sheet located in your mobile or on in-network computer?

Comment: @Ejaz I'm looking to update the excel spreadsheet located on a computer connected to the same network

Comment: To update your excel sheet, you can write your code in `Python/Java`. I prefer `python`. Create an api, maybe [flask-restful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), then call that `api` through your react-native code.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what to learn, I would think that an Excel Add-In would do this (since it means reading and writing the document from your app). There is a starter guide for this using React here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react

In the interest of a shortcut... If all you're doing is a lookup and then updating/adding a row inside a shared OneDrive Excel file or Google Sheet file's row, I believe you can use Zapier to do this with your own Trigger/Search + Action (bottom of page: https://zapier.com/apps/excel/integrations) or using the Webhook functionality instead (https://zapier.com/apps/excel/integrations/webhook/11179/add-new-webhook-payloads-to-an-excel-spreadsheet)